# Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

I want to run my app in xamarin.forms but I faced this problem

Error       XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`, referenced by `SimpleInjector`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`, or remove the reference to `SimpleInjector`.              0

I'm using Couchbise.Lite packages as Database for my app
I'm using VS2022

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022

Or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Comment: It seems your `SimpleInjector` is referencing classes that are not included in your project.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of Couchbase.Lite you are using when getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the package [Couchbase.Lite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Couchbase.Lite/) on my side(with VS 2022) and figured out that the error only happened on `Version 3.0.0`.Using `Version 2.8.6` or below is functioning well.